# Why is a complete measure space called “complete”?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

Things in mathematics are usually called “complete” for an obvious reason. A metric space is complete when you run out of Cauchy sequences without limits. A field is complete when you run out of polynomials without solutions. It is not clear what, if anything, you run out of in a complete measure space. The most obvious contender is that a complete measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ can’t be extended, in the sense that there exist no $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}\supset\mathcal{F}$ (containment is strict) and measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\nu|_{\mathcal{F}}=\mu$. But the measurable space $(\{a,b\},\{\emptyset,\{a,b\}\})$ equipped with any measure provides an easy counterexample. However, my trick here is cheap. My space is not, to abuse terminology, $T_0$. We could introduce an equivalence relation on $\Omega$ of being members of precisely the same sets of $\mathcal{F}$, and require that the equivalence classes be singletons. So would this result apply to “$T_0$” complete measure spaces. If not, why are they called complete?

Comment: Run out of? I don’t understand this sentiment. Metric completeness really does mean the space is complete; it has no holes, all Cauchy sequences converge inside the space. Algebraic completeness is the same; every polynomial is fully contained inside the field, which is a natural meaning of completeness.

Comment: And similarly with a complete measure space there are no unmeasurable sets which are subsets of sets of measure $0$

Comment: Start with a metric space. Add points representing non-convergent Cauchy sequences as in the construction of the completion. When you reach the completion, you have run out. Similarly with algebraic completions. I guess you do run out of "unmeasurable sets which are subsets of sets of measure $0$" in a complete measure space, but that doesn't feel important enough among all the things in a measure space as to deserve the term "complete".

Comment: As @FShrike says completeness can be thought as having no holes. For example, if you pick the Cauchy sequence $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.145 \dots$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ its nonconvergence can be seen as a "hole" in the place of $\pi$. The sequence "should be" convergent but there is a hole in the place where the limit would be. In a complete metric space all those holes have disappeared and the Cauchy property is equivalent to convergence.

Comment: If $A$ is measurable, and $A\triangle B$ (the symmetric difference) is a null-space, then completeness implies that $B$ is measurable (and of course $\mu (B)=\mu (A)$). I think it's reasonable to think of $B$ as a hole that's filled out. We typically can't have *all* sets measurable, but completion fills out all "holes" that are "very close" to already measurable sets.

Comment: Basically, all sets that "should" have the same measure as an already measurable set (in the precise sense above), will be measurable.

Comment: Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{M}$ of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0, 1]$ is complete, but if $E$ is a subset of $[0, 1]$ that is not Lebesgue measurable, then there are many ways to extend $\lambda$ to a measure on the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{M} \cup \{E\}.$ (I'm in the middle of writing an answer to another Maths.SE question, setting out a detailed proof of this result.) I think this answers the part of your question concerned with "$T_0$" spaces, but unfortunately not the part about the reason for the use of the term "complete".